Override root style does not work after material-ui upgrade to mui
I migrated from material-ui 4.11.4 to mui 6.1.5, i use <StyledEngineProvider>, i read the https://mui.com/material-ui/migration/troubleshooting/ and  https://mui.com/material-ui/migration/v5-style-changes/. Seems there should be no need to adjust my style overrides, but they don't work. In dev tools i see this style is overriden by the MuiButton root style. e.g. this code worked before:
const useStyles = makeStyles<Theme, StyleProps>((theme: Theme) => ({
  button: {
    color: theme.palette.text.primary,
    padding: '16px 26px',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    textTransform: 'none',
    letterSpacing: 0,
    width: '100%'
  } ...

<Button className={classes.button}

To make it work now i am doing this:
const useStyles = makeStyles<Theme, StyleProps>((theme: Theme) => ({
 root: {
  "& .MuiButtonBase-root": {
    color: theme.palette.text.primary,
    padding: '16px 26px',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    textTransform: 'none',
    letterSpacing: 0,
    width: '100%'
  }
 }...

and apply this to a parent of the Button. But i suspect this should not be necessary and there is a easier solution to the problem.
